# Drawbacks of Bonding Earth & neutral in Industrial sub panels

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

Bonding of Earth and neutral in machine subpanels will causes problem, but I want to know how it would affect PLC & VFD, etc.

The machine has 2 panels one for heaters (uneven load in each phase) another has VFD (250 kW) for the motor. since the last 4 months continuously facing a problem with drive most of the time control board failed without any error replaced with new VFD but no improvement. Also found some liquid from boards maybe electrolyte.

While checking found both panel earth & neutral & bonded together. I removed the bonding but want to make sure it was the root cause of all the time drive failure.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. 250+ kW power systems aren't in our "home improvement" area; you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 250+ kW power systems aren't "home improvement".

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove earth-neutral bonding unless you are sure both neutral and earth have genuine, quality separate paths back to the main panel.

**Dirt is not a genuine, quality path**.  So if the only path back is via dirt using grounding rods at each panel, you need to hardwire a ground wire.  Ground rods are for returning lightning, not human-made current.

However, earth-neutral bonding elsewhere than the main panel creates a serious safety issue that might also damage equipment.  If there is trouble in the shared neutral-ground, there can be extraordinary voltages on both neutral (which may hurt equipment) and ground (which may hurt people).

So yes, a neutral break could cause voltages as high as the opposite phase voltage. So if your service is 240/416V wye, you could see 416V between neutral and hot.  You could also see voltage as high as 176V between "things which should be grounded" and genuine earth.